# Generalization of $\underbrace{f(f(f(\cdots f(x))))}_{k \text{ times}}$ for polynomial functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

\begin{align}
f^k(x) & = \underbrace{f(f(f(\cdots f(x))))}_{k \text{ times}} \\[2ex]
f(x) & = mx + b \\[10ex]
f^1(x) & = mx + b \\
& = xm^1 + bm^{0}\\[2ex]
f^2(x) & = m(xm + b) + b\\
& = xm^{2} + bm^{1} + bm^{0}\\[2ex]
f^3(x) & = m(xm^{2} + bm + b) + b\\
& = xm^{3} + bm^{2} + bm^{1} + bm^{0}
\end{align}

As observed, $f^{k}(x) = xm^{k} + b(m^{0} + m^{1} + m^{2} + \cdots + m^{k - 3} + m^{k - 2} + m^{k - 1} )$

Say

$S = m^{0} + m^{1} + m^{2} + \cdots + m^{k - 3} + m^{k - 2} + m^{k - 1}$

$\text{Multiply both sides by } m$

$Sm = m^{1} + m^{2} + m^{3} + \cdots + m^{k - 2} + m^{k - 1} + m^{k}$

The only thing that changed is that $m^{0}$ (equals $1$) was subtracted and $m^{k}$ was added, so we have the equation

$Sm = S + m^{k} - 1$

$Sm - S = m^{k} - 1$

$S(m - 1) = m^{k} - 1$

$S = \frac{m^{k} - 1}{m - 1}$

Substuting that in

$f^{k}(x) = xm^{k} + b(\frac{m^{k} - 1}{m - 1})$

This allows to generalize the definition and include things like $f^{1.5}(x)$ or $f^{2i + 5}(x)$.

The only case that the formula doesn't work is when $m = 1$ (divides by 0), i guess that's because it makes the function to only have addition as operation.

Are there similar formulas for higher degree polynomials?

Comment: This doesn't allow you to "calculate things like $f^{1.5}(x)$" as that has no prior definition. It gives you a way of generalising the usual definition of functional composition to arbitrary exponents in the very special case when the function you are starting with is affine. Do you have any application for this?

Comment: I have asked a related question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4779803/given-analytic-fx-find-fx-such-that-forall-x-fx-ffx and have linked your question in the body of that question.

Comment: @RobArthan You're right, I should rephrase it

Comment: Though $\lim_{m \to 1} \frac{m^k-1}{m-1} = k$. This makes sense since for $f(x)=x+b$, $f^k(x)=x+kb$ is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's in general no such formulas for polynomials of higher degree. Of course, there are very particular cases where there is possible ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Examples)), like $f(x)=x^2$, but even for polynomials as simple as $f(x)=x^2+1$ there's no formula.

The [Logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) is an example of how a very simple polynomial ($f(x) = rx(1-x)$) turn out to be very complex. Another one is the [Mandelbrot fractal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set) which arises from studying another simple polynomial: $f(x) = x^2+c$

Comment: Actually the two examples are essentially the same.  If $f(x) = r x (1-x)$, then with $h(t) =   r \left(\dfrac{1}{2}-t\right)$ (so $h^{-1}(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} - \dfrac{x}{r}$) and $c = \dfrac{2r - r^2}{4}$ we have $h(f(h^{-1}(x))) = x^2 + c$.

Comment: I actually derived an infinite series about 40 years ago (before the internet!) to find f(x) such that f(f(x)) = F(x), given a real analytic function F(x) which has a real fixed point, i.e. a value $\lambda$ such that $F(\lambda)=\lambda$. Obviously, it doesn't work for $x^2+1$, but does for $x^2-1$! It would probably take me a some time to re-derive it.